# Cannot deploy a pdf by a link from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, filepath

I'm trying to add a PDF file to a website which uses the Sinatra framework when I add:

`get "/test" do
    return send_file File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "pdf",  'ebook.pdf')
end`

I can get the ebook by going to /test

However the ebook needs to be linked to via an image, here's an excerpt from my html:

```
<a href="/test"><img src="/static/images/ebook_image.png" title="Download Ebook"></a>
```

It doesn't work when I click the link, I assume it has something to do with the File.join but I've tried several modifications and can't get it to work.

EDIT: Somehow it works when I do "open in new tab" but not when I click the link directly.

Comment: Why not just put the PDF file in the filesystem accessible to Sinatra as a static file?  <a href="/static/pdf/ebook.pdf"> or some such.

Comment: It'd help if you can add the error/behaviour you're seeing when you click on the link.